# RegExp not returning the desired results

Tags: regex

I would expect the following code to return these two lines

88518-008

89274-021(08518-008,09274-021)

But it is only returning the second one, and I don't understand why, any help would be great!

```
WITH DATA AS
(
    SELECT   '88518-008,89274-021(08518-008,09274-021)' str
        FROM dual
)
SELECT   TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^,]+\((.+)\)|[^,]+(?![^\(]*\))+', 1, LEVEL)) str
FROM DATA
CONNECT BY REGEXP_INSTR(str, '\,(?![^\(]*\))', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
```

I have tested the regex online and they work as expected, and pulled the query from another example and tried replacing the values to match my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, The below returns the desired results

```
WITH DATA AS
   (
       SELECT 'word1, word2, word3, word4, word5, word6 (word7, word8)' str FROM dual
   )
SELECT   trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+\((.+)\)|[^,]+(?![^\(]*\))+|[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
FROM DATA
CONNECT BY REGEXP_INSTR(str, ',', 1, LEVEL) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the following regex:

```
'([^,]*),(.*\([^\)]+\))'
```

It starts by creating a `Group 1`, matching anything but `comma`, then a `comma`, then creates a `Group 2`, mathing anything up to `left parenthes`, then a `left parenthes`, then anything up to a `right parenthes` and finally a `right parenthes`.

That will give you the first value in `Group 1`, and the second value in `Group 2`.